Trying to figure out the best and worst case time complexity of a function. Is it possibly that worst and best case are the same?
I've been asked to find the best and worst case time complexity "in terms of their running time as a function of input size, n." I'm pretty new to Big O but I was doing okay will the other problems until this one.
void func2(int a[], int n)
{
   int woo = 0;
   for(int i=0; i<n ; i++) {
      for(int j=0 ; j<n ; j++) {
         woo += a[i]*a[j];
         if (woo == 10000) {
            j = n;
         }
      }
   }
}

Worst case: is O(n^2) because there are nested for loops.
Best case: Also seems like O(n^2) because even if the condition woo == 10000 is met that only exits the loop the single time it happens. As n increases the inner loop still executes more and more times. So is it still n^2? Or is it some kind of n(n-1) kind of thing (which isn't that still just n^2?
I'd appreciate any help or explanation on this <3 Thanks
I copied and ran the code in my IDE to test various situations. No matter the array data as n increases it runs an exponential number of times.

This is more a question about the analysis of algorithms, not computer programming per se. (The computer program has already been written and debugged.)


Best case: Also seems like O(n^2) because even if the condition woo == 10000 is met that only exits the loop the single time it happen.

The thing is that it can happen more than a single time. Imagine a product where one of its operands is 0, then the sum woo doesn't change, and we could have a repetition.
We can get into this situation if we have an array of only zeroes, except for its first value, which would be 100.
Then the very first product that is calculated is a[0]*a[0], which is 100*100, i.e. 10000. Any other product will have a zero as operand and so now every time that if is executed, the loop is exited.
That means that the inner loop never makes more than one iteration, and the only loop that really "loops" is the outer one. And so we get a best case of O().

Worst Case: O(n^2), when the condition if (woo == 10000) is never satisfied, and the inner loop runs fully for every i.
Best Case: O(n^2), when the condition is met on the first iteration of the inner loop, causing an early exit from the if condition but the for inner for loop will execute for the complete iteration(all values of i).
